# How to set two different states in one fetch call (React Native)?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get vaccine data from a website called [Vaccine Spotter](https://www.vaccinespotter.org/). Since there are two objects (metadata) and features (which includes all the locations and their addresses). I'm trying to get the metadata for how many locations there are in a certain state. I'm trying to get the features object to get the locations of the vaccine centers, their website URLs, and their addresses. How can I set up a useEffect() function in React Native to get both the metadata keys and the features keys in the JSON File. The JSON file can be found [here](https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/CO.json).

My code can be found below:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/' + stateAbb + '.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setData(json.metadata))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
```

I tried adding another fetch call to get another object in the JSON file, but that didn't work as the object is still undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/' + stateAbb + '.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setData(json.metadata))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
fetch('https://www.vaccinespotter.org/api/v0/states/' + stateAbb + '.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setPropData(json.features))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, [stateAbb]);
```

where stateAbb is the state abbreviation of the location the user selects. I plan to render the components using a flatlist tag shown below:

```
{isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <FlatList
      data={propData.properties}
      keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <VaccineRow
          name={item.name} 
          url={item.url}
          vaccineName={''}
          enabled={false}
          address={'HI'}
          //figure out the onpress as a dummy
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.url)}
        />
      )}
    />
  )}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could write multiple `setState` statements in one fetch command.

```
fetch()
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  setState1();
  setState2();
  }
.catch()
.finally();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's only working for the first state and not the other. How can I implement the second state?

Comment: can you tell what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sure! I'm trying to access the metadata object and then the store_count variable inside the object from the Vaccine Spotter JSON file. It says that data.metadata.store_count is undefined, even though data.metadata is an object.

Comment: insert console.log(data.metadata); before setState1(); and can you show me that?

Comment: It says [Object, Object] as the result, but accessing any object in metadata results in undefined.

Comment: I tried the API and it is working fine. Create a Snack Expo and share.

Comment: @ProgrammingMaestro Please only include the specific part of your problem that can be reproduced. Its hard to find bug in the whole app.

Comment: ResultsPage.js, specifically the useEffect() hook is where the bug is

Comment: see this: https://snack.expo.io/@vipulchandra04/0248ac

Comment: If you see the console, there are 2 'undefined' and 1 json.features logged. 2 'undefined's are because 'features' is updated after 2nd rendering, till then 'features' is undefined.

Comment: You should use a function to conditionally render only is 'features' is defined